# "Error showing an incoming reccurrence notification" in Windows 7

Tags: vb.net, dom, notifications

This code:

```
(Imports Microsoft.Toolkit.Uwp.Notifications)

Try
   Dim nts As New ToastContentBuilder()
   nts.SetToastScenario(ToastScenario.Reminder)
   nts.AddText(My.Resources.Messages.Recourrences)
   nts.AddText(SomeText)
   nts.SetToastDuration(ToastDuration.Long)
   nts.Show()
```

works in Win10 but generates this "ex.message" error in Windows 7:

> Error showing an incoming reccurrence notification.
> Could not find Windows Runtime type
> 'Windows.Data.Xml.Dom.XmlDocument'

The PC with Win7 has installed the "Microsoft .NET Framework Version =  4.8.03761".

Why? How to avoid the error in Win7?

Comment: Not much UWP / WinUI support in Windows 7

Comment: I doubt you can avoid the error in Windows 7.  Windows.Data.Xml.Dom.XmlDocument appears to be Windows 10 only based on the documentation.  Note that Windows 7 has been out of support for ~1 year now.

Comment: Ok, ty mates for the replies